# how to hide sidebar when mouse cursor goes on menubar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide sidebar when mouse cursor goes on menu bar which is in navigation bar to hide the sidebar.

I tried to hide it many ways but it did not worked for me so looking for any alternative.

Side should be hide once the mouse curser is on the menu bar

[image]
[image]

Here is my CSS code :

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

body{
   background-color: #f3f5f9;
}



.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 78px;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}


.navbar a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-inline-start: 45px;
  padding: 26px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}


.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}


.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .sidebar{
  width: 150px;
  top: 78px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4b4276;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position:fixed;
  transition: all 0.5s ease ;
}



.wrapper .sidebar ul li{
  
  padding: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(15, 3, 85, 0.05);
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}    

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a{
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas{
  width: 45px;
  
}

.sub-menu-1{
  display: none;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 92%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px ;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li .dropdown{
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover{
  background-color:#d59bf6 ;
}
    
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a{
  color: rgb(70, 9, 105);
}
```

tried to hide the side bar but was unable to do so

Comment: you should post html code also

Comment: post pictures of the ui you have right now and the ui you want to achieve.